# Is there an automatic way where python select the variables that makes the most sense in an OLS regression?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression, rpy2

Suppose I have the following Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np, statsmodels.formula.api as smf

# Generate the data
Stocks=100
mean = [0.5, 1000, 10]
Var = [0.5, 60, 3]

A=np.random.normal(loc=0.5,scale=0.5,size=(Stocks, 1))

for a, b in zip(mean, Var):
    A=np.concatenate((A, np.random.normal(loc=a,scale=b, size=(Stocks,1))), axis=1)

df1=pd.DataFrame(A, columns=['Betas','M/B','Size', 'P/E'])

df1['PAR_stock']=0.08+0.801*df1['Size']+0.321*df1['M/B']+0.164*df1['P/E']-0.084*df1['Betas']
```

and I now have the following DataFrame. I want to select the variables that make the best fit between Beta, size and P/E and M/B.

```
formula = 'PAR_stock ~ Betas + Size + Q("P/E") + Q("M/B")'
results = smf.ols(formula, df1).fit()
print(results.summary())
```

I want python to do each and tell me which variables are the best to use in an OLS regression and tell me that this is the best model.

Is there a way to do this in python using machine learning codes.

To the best of my knowledge, there is a library in R, called `glmulti` is there something similar in python?

PS: I am still new to this so please do not be harsh in your comments. If you have any suggestion or a book that explains these things explicitly feel free to share it. Thank you for your co-operation

Comment: Define "best model". What is the "best" model depends on the usage and on the restrictions that you want to impose on the model. Regularized machine learning methods are usually targeted to "best prediction". But that doesn't mean that that model "makes the most sense" in terms of interpretation.

Comment: @Josef please have a read of the glmulti function available here https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v034i12

Comment: I have never seen this, at least not beyond model averaging for prediction. There are examples on stackoverflow using loops over all models in the candidate set using aic or some cross-validation fit measure. I opened https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/6237 especially for the uncertainty estimates and multimodel inference which would be appropriate for statsmodels.